# PyQt5 scrolling with mouse

Tags: python, pyqt5

**What i want to do:**

Scroll a pyqt5 window scroll-area with the mouse.

**Problem:**

If scroll-area has Q*Edit (for example QDateTimeEdit), the scroll stops in Q*Edit and the mouse scroll change the Q*Edit Widget.

**Why i want this:**

I want some screen-shots with PicPick program. So when the program scroll the window to capture it, the scroll stops to a scrolled Widget (example QDateTimeEdit).

It seem's i have to set/disable focus policy, but i don't know how to do this.

I found some code:

```
for i in range(1,60):
        

        layout_name = "gridLayout_"+str(i)
        if(hasattr(ui, layout_name)):
            layout = getattr(ui, layout_name)
            items = (layout.itemAt(i) for i in range(layout.count())) 
            for w in items:
                if(hasattr(w, "setFocusPolicy")):
                    w.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
```

But it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Your question is a bit obscure. You want the scrolling to stop when a specific widget is shown? Why is that, and what is the utility in that from the program's perspective?

Comment: No i want the opossite. I want the scrolling to continue while widgets are shown in the screen.

Comment: @ChrisP please provide a [mre]